# Reputation changing between page visits

Tags: support, reputation

My reputation just went a little odd a few moments ago. It started off on 11,334 at which point I made a comment to a post.

Then I noticed it had jumped up to 11,350 but I had no notifications of any votes (and the usual + indicator).

[image]

So I clicked on my profile and immediately the rep went back to the 11,334 that I expected.

[image]

Looking at the reputation history there aren't any changes in there. Does anyone know what might be causing this random fluctuation?

[image]

Comment: The reputation in the topbar only shows positive changes, so there won't be a notification, but the most likely change would be a post which you had a +16 was deleted.  In your [retuation feed](http://stackoverflow.com/users/134346/ian?tab=reputation&sort=post) you should see a check box for "Show Removed Posts".  I'd check that and see if there were any deleted posts recently

Comment: I missed the part about starting at 11,334.  In that case I'd say you had someone probably accept an answer of yours and then unaccept it (can't explain the other 1 point though).  Changes that happen in the same day like someone upvoting and then immediately unupvoting are not recorded.

Comment: @psubsee2003: Ah you're right - me being daft. I had an answer I deleted a while before, this must have been an open tab that still had the old value and I'd missed the fact it'd been at 11,350 at some point. Doh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topbar never will show negative reputation events, so anything that causes you to lose rep will not be displayed.

For large bits of rep that are lost (more than just a downvote), there are usually only a few explanations:

- A positively score post of yours was deleted (either a question was deleted, or you answered a question that was deleted).
- A user was removed and his/her votes were thrown out as well.
- Someone unaccepted or unupvoted a post of yours.

The first bullet (deleted post) will appear in your reputation feed only when you click the "Show Removed Posts" at the bottom of the reputation tab, but are otherwise hidden.  This will show the specific post(s) that was/were deleted.

The 2nd bullet will always show in your reputation feed as "user was removed".  This will **not** show specific posts as it could reveal voting information, especially when notable users leave the site (which has happened before).  All you will see is the "user was removed" entry and the associated loss of rep.

For rapid changes (a quick increase followed by a quick decrease) the 3rd bullet is usually the culprit (someone accepted your answer or upvoted a post, then changed their mind and immediately undid the action).  Those will normally show the positive change, but not the negative change or you could appear to jump by +10 or +15 but you don't drop until you reload the page.  And these events will not appear in your reputation feed either if they happen on the same day.